# Flutter error of shared_prefrences in release mode of apk (No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

**shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4**

**Error log:**
`MissingException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)`

**flutter sdk details:**

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G7016 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/taleb/Developer/flutter
> • Framework revision 7891006299 (6 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
> • Engine revision ae90085a84
> • Dart version 2.10.4

> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at /Users/taleb/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/taleb/Library/Android/sdk
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
> • All Android licenses accepted.

> [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
> Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
> Or install Xcode via the App Store.
> Once installed, run:
> sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
> • CocoaPods version 1.8.3

> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin installed
> • Dart plugin version 201.9317
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
> • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
> • Flutter plugin version 45.1.2
> • Dart plugin version 193.7547

> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • SM A107F (mobile) • R9AM905ZREJ • android-arm • Android 10 (API 29)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: shared preferences is one of those package the updates frequently and they normally haven't backward compatibility. I choose to use a fix version. Right now I am using `0.5.7+3` which is working without issue for me in any mode. Check this solution it may help you.

Comment: @mahdishahbazi Thanks for your help , i also test release mode with 0.5.7+3 version, but i still have problem with prefrs :(

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @mahdishahbazi In the release mode i can't see the log , i just tested with removing prefrs and i see everything ok and when i added prefrs i got problem!!!
for example in the "splashPage" of the app i'm checking user is logged in or not  with prefrs and i still remain in the "splashPage" and nothing happend...

Comment: @Taleb try to use `FlutterError.onError` or `ErrorWidget.builder` to show your error on a screen or log into a log file.

Comment: @mahdishahbazi Thanks for your good suggestion,now i can see the log: `MissingException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)`

Comment: @Taleb This normally happens when you add a package that use native code but won't build your app and try to use hot reload and hot restart. But as you mentioned if it's in release mode you are definitely build app and you can't use hot restart.

Comment: @mahdishahbazi Yeah exactly, It's work in the debug mode but in the release mode throw that exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using shared_preferences 0.2.4 and above, use `setMockInitialValues`:

```
SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({}); // set initial values here if desired
```

For earlier versions you can do it manually:

```
const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences')
  .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
      return <String, dynamic>{}; // set initial values here if desired
    }
    return null;
  });
```